# Multi-document summarization in python

Tags: python, nlp

I could only find github.com/sildar/potara available right now. All tools seem to offer to only single document summarization techniques but none offering multi-document approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Not a library, but you can extract the source code. This one uses SumBasic

https://github.com/xiamx/ns

Comment: Cool! Add a demo if possible, how I can call it from python. That is, pass a search quey and get the text.